# how to stop mongodb-kafka connector stop

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am using mongo-kafka connector on my standalone kafka node.
Is there any gracious way(not using kill method) to kill mongo-kafka connector process.

Answer (score 0):

Refer Connect REST API `/connectors/:name/pause` endpoint

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest

Comment: How can I `pause` with KafkaConnector resource and not with REST API?

Comment: @ZviMints I assume you are using Strimzi? This question was not about it, I suggest creating a new post